# Composer query does not work on array of concepts

Tags: hyperledger-composer

We have an asset which has an Array of Concepts. And we are tying to query this asset using a condition on this array which is not working.

Sample Model (v0.16.0):

```
concept MyConcept {  
o String Name  
o String value  
} 

asset MyAsset identified by myAssetId{  
o String myAssetId  
o MyConcept[] myConceptArray   
}
```

We would like to write a query that would do something like

```
SELECT MyAsset WHERE myConceptArray CONTAINS {"name":field1, "value": "somevalue"}.
```

Is this possible?

Right now, query (CONTAINS) seems to be working only on array of strings.

Comment: Information provided in Rocket Chat: https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/composer?msg=WGTN7hEfTczRdq7au

Comment: Thank you Thatcher. It is very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as indicated by R Thatcher - adding the following wiki link by way of answer and permanence -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#information_source--queries-and-query-support--examples (scroll down to example entitled `CONTAINS Example 3: single-value search (Concept) in a query` or `CONTAINS Example 4: multi-field Concept with 'OR' example')`

Comment: Thank you Mahony. In our case, we have used multi-field concept with 'AND' operator as well and it worked.